# Как можно программно заменить цвет элемента в navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, android-menu

Есть `NavigationDrawer` в котором расположены MenuItem'ы. Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на элемент приложение открывало указанный раздел, а `MenuItem`поменял цвет текста и цвет фона, указывая, на каком разделе находится пользователь.ВАЖНО: Цвет меняется не на момент нажатия на кнопку, а меняется в результате выполнения кода Как это можно реализовать? Можно ли коммандами поменять все в отдельности или же применить заранее готовый стиль к выбранному `MenuItem`?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте к `NavigationView`:

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background"  // цвет фона
app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_color_list"  //  цвет текста
app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_color_list"  //  цвет иконки
```

В папке `drawable` создайте nav_item_background.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/gray" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/gray" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/gray" />  // выбранный итем
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />  // обычный итем
</selector>
```

В папке `res` создайте папку `color` и в ней nav_color_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_checked="true" />  // выбранный итем
    <item android:color="@color/textColorPrimaryLight" />  // обычный итем
</selector>
```

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли меня или же я неправильно выразился. Итем должен окрашиваться в результате выполнения кода и меняться динамически.

Comment: В вопросе вы спросили, как сделать, чтобы цвет менялся при нажатии на итем. Тут как раз это и описано.

Comment: Сейчас проправлю, но в заглавии написано именно Программно